# Capturing a function from a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

(This is perhaps better checked with Facebook page.)

The Facebook page has a function

```
 onclick="return fc_click(this);"
```

bound to any **comment**.

If someone clicks on a comment as above, I want to let it execute the above function. But also above that I wish to capture this function itself, for further action. Is it possible?

Comment: You want to run another function with the result of that function, correct?

Comment: Please elaborate on "_capture this function itself, for further action_".

Comment: correct... something on the lines of Brad's idea below. But while `var old_on_click = $(event.target).attr("onclick")` or something similar

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called "monkey patching" or "duck punching".  Basically, you replace that function `fc_click()` with your own, and then call `fc_click()`.

```
var old_fc_click = fc_click;
fc_click = function (thisVal) {
    var result = old_fc_click.call(this, thisVal);
    console.log(result);
}
```

Now, this won't work so great for Facebook unless you are making a browser extension, but that is the general idea.

Comment: I'd just typed out this exact same thing - even down to the variable name!

Comment: @benjaminbenben- Would you?

Comment: @Brad you are amazing. Thanks a lot for this idea. I will apply this for now. However, this works only for Facebook. What I want to do is every time something occurs in onclick, I want to capture that function so that I could use it just in place of old_fc_click...

Would `var old_on_click = $(event.target).attr("on click")` work always?

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi, You're saying that you want to catch click events for everything?  Why not just use `$(body).click(function () { /* your code here */ });` and pay attention to the value of `this`?  Or do you need the return value of all on-click functions?  Keep in mind too that not all `onclick` functions are actually in the attribute for the HTML element.

Comment: @Brad, actually that's what I am doing. in the '$(this).click(function()' I need to separate cases which have onclick functions defined. Now, with Facebook, the behavior is a bit wilder. Once you click on the comment, the comment box appears with all previous comments and the comment box is focused. Because this comment box is sometimes hidden, I am unable to capture the id for this input (comment box) and so the brainstorming :(

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi, Why don't you post a new question with specifically what you are trying to accomplish, and we might suggest an alternative way?  I'm having trouble guessing at what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am not sure, if I did a good job, but the separate question is here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801150/capturing-id-of-a-comment-box-in-facebook)