# Capturing id of a comment box in Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I need to fetch the id of a comment box in Facebook upon click. However, many a times, a comment box is not displayed by default, but when a user clicks on the **comment** link, it is displayed with previous comments via the function

```
  onclick="return fc_click(this);"
```

Does anyone know how to fetch this id for the comment box it?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: So, you are writing a browser extension?  What does it do?  You want to get the comment box when a user clicks in a comment box?  For what purpose?  Give us as much relevant information as possible.

Comment: sort of. I am developing an application in which the webpages are displayed as a summary page and if clicked on a text box input for typing, the page is loaded zoomed on the element user clicked. Now, this autofocusing is achieved by writing a temporary cookie which contains the id of the clicked item. With Facebook, the comment boxes are collapsed in general and so can't access the id simply using this method.